# i am having a problem reading out a data from firebase collection using react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am able to get all the documents
but i need to get the datas i want and that is where my problem is.i want to query to the point of getting the _fl_meta

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHAJK.png)

[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLpxT.png)

Comment: i will be glad if you can assist.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.